# Get all oids by ifindex ID and wildcard

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Is there a way to get all OIDs by a given ifIndex ID using a wildcard?  Say I have:

```
IF-MIB::ifIndex.513 = INTEGER: 513
```

Is there a way using snmpget or snmpbulkwalk to get only:

```
IF-MIB::ifIndex.513 = INTEGER: 513
IF-MIB::ifDescr.513 = STRING: Gi0/1
IF-MIB::ifType.513 = INTEGER: propVirtual(53)
IF-MIB::ifMtu.513 = INTEGER: 1420
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.513 = Gauge32: 0
```

The best way I can figure this out at present is to snmpwalk the device and use "| grep 513", which would be highly inefficient the more index id's I need to perform this on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send single SNMP-GET request with **multiple variable bindings** to get the information you need:

```
snmpget -c public -v 2c <router_ip_address> ifIndex.513 ifDescr.513 ifType.513 ifMtu.513 ifSpeed.513
```

Comment: This does appear to be the best (due to being the only way).  I was hoping for a wildcard action.  Thank you.